# Convert seconds to milliseconds in vb

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert the str_Delay value to ms(millisecond). I tried the following am getting result as 0. Please help in this.

```
  Dim str_Delay As Integer = "0.01"
  Dim str_Delay1 As Integer
  str_Delay1 =  
  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(str_Delay).
                    TotalMilliseconds)
  MsgBox(str_Delay1)
```

Comment: isn't that VB.Net ?

Comment: If you used [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) it would tell you that you should not be trying to directly assign the string`"0.01"` to an integer. An integer is a whole number, so it can't represent 0.01 anyway.

Comment: And drop the (inaccurate) Hungarian notation. `str_Delay` is an Integer and is misleading. Just use variables named `delay` and `delay1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are 1000 milliseconds in a second, so just convert the string to number, and multiply by 1000 :

```
str_Delay1 = Val(str_Delay) * 1000
```

Comment: He's converting from seconds to milliseconds so needs to multiply (not divide) by 1000,

Answer (score 0):

Change your data types to `Double`. You cannot represent `0.01` as an Integer. If you debug your code and look at your values, it's not that the conversion to milliseconds is resulting in `0`, `str_Delay` is `0` to begin with. So of course the final result is zero as well.

```vb
Dim str_Delay As Double = 0.01
Dim str_Delay1 As Double = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(str_Delay).TotalMilliseconds

MsgBox(str_Delay1)
```